# Difference between a < x < b and x < a, x > b when finding increasing or decreasing function?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functions

I have been looking at how to find increasing and decreasing functions using differentiation. To give an example of what I am looking at a typical question in this area of mathematics would consist of:

Is *f(x) = 3x<sup>3</sup> - 2x* an increasing or decreasing function when *x < a and x > b*?

Would there be any difference if, instead of being given:

*x < a* and *x > b*

I was given *a < x < b*?

Would this change anything, in terms of whether the function is now increasing or decreasing?

I do know that if *dy/dx > 0* then the function is increasing, and so on and so forth, however I just need clarification on the above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$a<x<b$$ means "$a<x$ and $x<b$", which is different from "$a>x$ and $x>b$".  The former only gives values $x$ when $a<b$, while the latter only gives values $x$ when $a>b$.

Further, in the context of this specific question, the word "and" should be considered to be "or".  That is, this question has two parts: one for $x<a$, and the other for $x>b$.

Comment: When trying to find whether the function is increasing or decreasing, does the < or > change the answer in any way? With the example above I would work it out like so f(a) = 9(a)<sup>2</sup> - 2.

Comment: For $x<a$ means on the interval $(-\infty,a)$.  For $x>b$ means on the interval $(b,+\infty)$.

Comment: So when x < a, would f(x) be f(a), and when x > a, would f(x) be f(-a)?

Answer (score 1):

we have $$f(x)=3x^3-2x$$ thus we get $$f'(x)=9x^2-2$$ and we can solve $$f'(x)>0$$ if $$x^2>\frac{2}{3}$$ and we get $$|x|>\frac{\sqrt{2}}{3}$$ can you finish?
and for $$X\geq 0$$ we get $$x\geq \frac{\sqrt{2}}{3}$$ or for $$x<0$$ we find $$x<-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{3}$$

Comment: The OP was about the grammar and interpreting what the question is asking.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $a \lt b$, which would be normal for questions like this, $a \lt x \lt b$ lets $x$ range between $a$ and $b$, while $x\lt a$ and $x \gt b$ is the rest of the real line.  In particular, a cubic with positive leading coefficient can increase from very negative values to a local maximum, decrease for a while to a local minimum, then increase without bound.  If $a,b$ are chosen as the extrema, the function will be decreasing when $a \lt x \lt b$ and increasing when $x \lt a$ and when $x \gt b$.  When you see "$x \lt a$ and $x \gt b$" you need to figure out from context whether you are being given two conditions and asked for two answers, one that applies when $x \lt a$ and another (which might be different) that applies when $x \gt b$ or the two conditions are supposed to be true simultaneously.  If $a \lt b$ in this example, that would be never, which would be an indication that you were supposed to consider the conditions separately.